# Find the probability it was produced from Nasik Factory

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The compressors used in refrigerators are manufactured by three different factories at Pune, Nasik and Nagpur.  It is known that the Pune factory produces twice as many compressors as the Nasik one, which produces the same number as the Nagpur one.  Experience also shows that 0.2% of the compressors produced at Pune as well as Nasik are defective and so are 0.4% of those 
produced at Nagpur.  A quality controller chooses a compressor and finds it a defective one.  What is the probability that it was produced at Nasik factory.

Comment: Ler $D$ be the event the thing is defective, and $B$ the event it was produced in Nasik. We want the conditional probability $\Pr(N\mid D)$. Tis is equal to $\frac{\Pr(N\cap B)}{\Pr(D)}$. Now you have two probabilities to compute.

Comment: Can you tell me the answer of this question

Comment: I will give a large start. The probability of $D$ is $(2/4)(0.002)+(1/4)(0.002)+(1/4)(0.004)$. Maybe the approach I suggest is not the one in your course, sometimes a "tree" approach. It will give the same answer.

Comment: P(Nasik and defective)= 0.006   P(Defective)= 0.025